# como capturar um id dinamicamente e em sequencia em postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, id, dinâmico

É referente a uma tabela de auditoria que estou criando, o objetivo em questão é registrar os campos da tabela em questão. Mas nao consigo capturar o id ex:

```
create or replace function audit_unidade.log_unidade_escola()
returns trigger as
$body$ 
begin
-- Aqui temos um bloco IF que confirmará o tipo de operação.
IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    INSERT INTO audit_unidade.escola (after_updade) 
        VALUES (
        (select 'id: ' || id || ' || ' || 'Tipo: ' || tipo_unidade || ' || ' || 'Escola: ' || nome_escola || ' || ' || 'CEP: ' || cep || ' || ' 
            || 'Bairro: ' || bairro || ' || ' || 'Rua: ' || ' || ' || rua || 'Nº: ' || numero || ' || ' || 'Email: ' || email || ' || ' || 'telefone1: ' ||
             coalesce(telefone1,'') || ' || ' || 'Telefone2: ' || coalesce(telefone2,'') || ' || ' || 'id_diretor: ' || id_diretor || 'id_secretario: ' ||
             id_secretario || ' || '  || 'id_coordenador1: ' || id_coordenador1 || ' || ' || 'id_coordenador2: ' || coalesce(id_coordenador2, 0)  
        from unidade.escola where id = (select nextval('unidade.escola_id_seq'))));
RETURN NEW;
END IF;
RETURN NULL;
end; $body$
language 'plpgsql'
```

eu tentei o comando `(select nextval('unidade.escola_id_seq')` acima mas não funciona, o campo da tabela "audit_unidade.escola" no campo "after_updade" apesar de não dar erro não registra nada referente a tabela "unidade.escola" por causa do id que não consigo capturar ficaria grato por essa ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Isso possivelmente está acontecendo porque a trigger está sendo executada antes dos dados serem efetivamente inseridos na tabela. Dessa forma, esse problema pode ser corrigido adicionando a condição **AFTER INSERT** na criação da trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER audit_unidade.log_unidade_escola_trigger AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON unidade.escola FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit_unidade.log_unidade_escola();
```